# How to fill asphalt driveway cracks?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

I need to seal-coat my driveway.

I need to fill hairline to 1/2" cracks first.

I tried the Home store liquid "crack filler" and was **extremely** disappointed in the results. (it shrunk and looks horrible)

I saw a 3 man team filling cracks as shown in the picture.

[image: city]

What do municipalities use to extend the life of their asphalt?

Can I buy the same product for my driveway and seal-coat over it?

Comment: Are you prepared to handle hot tar? And to heat it **without setting it on fire?** To put the fire out if you screw up not setting it on fire? If not, perhaps something more appropriate to home use (after all, municipalities don't seal-coat their roads) such as a less-liquid product in a caulking tube.

Comment: I used a filler that has to be melted with a blowtorch.  The repair was easy to make.  Neither the filler nor the asphalt caught on fire.  I used: https://smile.amazon.com/CRACK-STIX-Blacktop-Repair-125ft/dp/B00VLM7BNA/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=crack+stix&qid=1606234042&sr=8-2  (I just made the repair, so I do not know how well it will work and hold up. But it looks like it should work.)